# Error opening script file: D:/New Folder/RailsApplication1/script/rails (The system cannot find the path specified)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

when i am trying to generate model in netbeans, i am getting the below error. can some one please help me

Error opening script file: D:/New Folder/RailsApplication1/script/rails (The system cannot find the path specified)

Ruby on Rails application